# NodeJs Underscore sortby

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, underscore.js

i need to sort an array by its x value:

before sort

```
arr=>
[
  {x:0, y: 1234},
  {x:3, y: 324},
  {x:1, y: 3487},
]
```

after sort:

```
arr =>
[
  {x:0, y: 1234},
  {x:1, y: 3487},
  {x:3, y: 324},
]
```

and I m using NodeJs and CoffeeScript, I tried to use the Underscore's sortBy, but it won't work:

```
_.sortBy(arr, (x) -> arr.x)
```

Comment: You want `_.sortBy(arr, (item) -> item.x)`! `arr` does not have a `x` property…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
_.sortBy(arr, (item) -> item.x)
```

The second arg to `sortBy` is just a function that maps an item on the collection to the value you want to sort on. In this case the item on the collection is one of the objects in your array e.g. `{x:0, y: 1234}`. So you just need to pick the `x` property as the value to sort by.

Answer (score 1):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy):

> **sortBy** `_.sortBy(list, iterator, [context])`
>
> Returns a (stably) sorted copy of **list**, ranked in ascending order by the results of running each value through **iterator**. Iterator may also be the string name of the property to sort by (eg. `length`).

Note the last sentence. That means that there is a shortcut for the common case you're facing:

```
sorted = _(arr).sortBy('x')
```